# Handle system dialog (alert) in XCUITest with Swift 3 / Swift 4 in Xcode 9

Tags: swift3, swift4, xcode9, xcuitest

I want to write a XCUITest where I get a system dialog / alert. How can I handle it in Swift 3 / Swift 4 with Xcode 9?
It should find the alert and click one of the two displayed buttons.
Every time, if I search for the alert, the system can't find them.

```
XCUIApplication().alerts.element.exists // Will get nothing
XCUIApplication().alerts.element.buttons.element(boundBy: 0) // Will get nothing too.
```

Comment: `(lldb) po XCUIApplication().alerts.element(boundBy: 0)
    t =   274.61s Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 910
    t =   275.27s Find: Descendants matching type Alert
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 0x1702b1100
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    ↪︎Find: Element at index 0


(lldb) po XCUIApplication().alerts.buttons.count
    t =   300.49s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type Button
    t =   300.63s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 910
    t =   300.71s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using addUIInterruptionMonitor. This example below is to tap button Allow on system alert dialog box when it appears on the screen.

```
    addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System alert") { (alert) -> Bool in
        if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists {
            alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
        }
        return true
    }
```